# python tkinter code layout

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

Up until now i would create a different module for each interface, splash screen, login then main interface and pass each module the main_window.

```
class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I then pass this to each module. I am thinking there is a better way and a more organised way of creating tkinter GUI's. Do i create all of the screens in one module and call them or create separate modules?

**EDIT** An explaination on Tk and Toplevel would also be nice as i don't full understand them, i normally uses Tk()

I'm relatively new to uses class as objects, tk.Tk. Any advice or code layout examples would be nice.

Comment: `Tk` creates main window - you should use only one main window. `Toplevel` creates other windows - you can use many other windows. Maybe use `Frame` to create widgets and then you can add it to any window - `Tk` or `Toplevel`.

Comment: Is it healthy to create the main_window then pass the main window to each module via parameter or should i put all of the interface stuff in one file?

Comment: See other widgets - you always pass `parent` as first argument. It can be `Tk`, `Toplevel` or other widget ie. `Frame`. This way you can use it as main window or pop-up/dialog window or element in other widget.

Comment: OK, so do i create the entire interface for all my screens in one file or spread it out one file per screen?

Comment: it doesn't matter - if code is very long then use many files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets exist in a tree-like hierarchy with a single root. The root window is a `Toplevel`, though with a few other special behaviors because it is the root window. Both the single root window and all instances of `Toplevel` are independent windows floating on the screen.

For a tkinter application to work correctly you must have one root window, but you may have as many instances of `Toplevel` that you want. If you do not explicitly create a root window, one will be created the first time you try to create some other widget. You shouldn't write tkinter code that depends on this behavior. Explicit is better than implicit.

It's perfectly reasonable -- and often preferable -- to define each interface in a separate module, and pass the instance of the root window into the constructor of each other window.

Comment: Thank you! Is it also wise to create the frame for each widget which will be on the root window as a object like I have done for the main window as seen in my answer?

Comment: @JoshuaNixon: I don't know what you mean by "as seen in my answer". I don't see any answer of yours, and the code in your question doesn't contain any frames.

Comment: Thank you! Is it also wise to create the frame for each widget which will be on the root window as a object like I have done for the main window as seen in my question? I mean should i create each frame like how i do the main window. so create a class for each frame tk.Frame.__init__ etc